# Dashboard doesn't see Font Viewer

Tags: fonts

why ubuntu 12.04 dashboard doesn't show "Font Viewer" ?

gnome-font-viewer.desktop file is present in /usr/share/applications with entry
NoDisplay=true

running gnome-font-viewer in console immediately asks for a font name which is
totally unusefull.

How can we use this tool in a convenient windowing mode ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view a font, just double click its icon and Gnome font viewer will open up with your font!

If you don't know where your fonts are, they are in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype` and into their individual folders. Hope I answered!

EDIT : Try using fontforge, free software on the Software center or in terminal : `sudo apt-get install fontforge`.

Comment: Tanks for your answer; but the display supposes the font is ordinary latin and does not give its right unicode range (plane and bloc).  Clicking on ukai.ttc displays ordinary characters and not CJK glyphs. How can we get more infos on such fonts ?

Comment: Try using powerful tools such as fontforge.